# git fails to add files that have root only permissions

Tags: git

I am sitting on a cross development chair and created a JFFS2 file system to be used on the target.
Inside that tree are several directories and files that have root permissions only.
When I `git add` this tree I get
error: Unable to index file [file with problem]
fatal: adding files failed

I don't want to run git commands as root
And I don't want root priviledge needed on checkouts

How can I add this tree?

Thanx

Comment: Not a git issue, no program can read files only readable by root unless run by root.

Answer (score 6):

Git is good, but git is not capable of reading files it is not allowed to read.  You have conflicting requirements - root-only access to the files but not running git as root.

You will have to change one of the two requirements.  I recommend changing the permissions on the files.